# Как сделать внутреннюю тень у блока?

Tags: html, css, html5

Как сделать у блока подобную тень? Она начинается не от краёв блока, а идёт где-то внутри, от краёв она прозрачнее. Пробовал через inset, но тень начинается от края и выглядит ужасно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Обычный радиальный градиент на бэкграунде

Comment: Он даёт немного не такой эффект. который мне нужен..
https://sun9-54.userapi.com/impf/MrzCsPuUdqQwwHbqJTdV0Mx_Il5Zs66C3bzLog/iQaCFQPgJik.jpg?size=455x184&quality=96&proxy=1&sign=05bbc9f64bfdbf8b3da7c2a6e5caf092

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант с обычной тенью. Используем псевдоэлементы `:before`, `:after`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  height: 100px;
}

.number {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-family: fantasy;
  line-height: 100px;
  border: 8px dashed #e2ab46;
  border-radius: 300px;
  color: white;
  font-family: fantasy;
}

.name {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 2;
  border-bottom: 8px dashed #e2ab46;
  color: white;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.name span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 57px;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

.number:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 80px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.name:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0%;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 60px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="number"><span>13</span></div>
  <div class="name">
    <span>УРОВЕНЬ</span>до следующего уровня
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Не знаю в чём проблема с инсетом. Вот, кажется, норм вышло.

```css
div {
  background-color: #333;
  width: 300px;
  height: 170px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #eee;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-weight: 700;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 40px 80px #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 12px;
  background-clip: content-box;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px #000;
}
```

```html
<div>SOME TEXT</div>
```

Comment: Тут проблема в том, что этот блок будет использоваться поверх другого, который тоже должно быть видно. Тень под ним нужна только для того, чтобы его было лучше видно на светлом фоне. Ваше решение идеальное, но не подходит в моём конкретном случае :(